# Adding GeoDjango to an existing Django project

Tags: javascript, html, django, maps, geodjango

So, I was wondering if there is a way to implement GeoDjango into an existing Django project

```
Database:
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

Since I already did users and a few other stuff, I do not want to change my database, so is there a way to implement the GeoDjango into a basic Django project, and attach?

I need the maps so I could link it to several coffee shops on the front end on a basic HTML page. If there is a simpler, easier way to implement the maps, via JavaScript etc, please reply.

If there is a guide to doing it, please link it here.

Thank you for your replies!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To transfer your data from a sqlite db to a postgres db (with postgis) follow theses steps:

- Before mdifying your database settings, execute [`dumpdata`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata) to dump your data to a json file.
- Modify your `DATABASES` settings, create a new database and execute `migrate` to create all tables in the new database.
- Execute [`loaddata`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/django-admin/#loaddata) to load your old data into the new database.